# count number dictionaries which are a part of one dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Let's assume we have a list of dictionaries with nested dictionaries:

```
list1=[{'name':"Jon", 'grades':[{'maths': 4, 'biology':5}]},
       {'name':"Marry", 'grades':[{'maths': 5, 'biology':4, 'geography': 3}]}]
```

is there a way, without using a loop, to count number of pairs(key-value) only within 'grades' key?
So the expected result here would be a list [2,3]

Comment: The alternatives to using a loop are list/dict comprehension or the `itertools` library

Comment: It looks like the lists for the `grades` entries always have exactly one entry (a dict)?  If so, why not get rid of the lists?  They serve no purpose other than to make it more tedious to get to the dict.

Comment: What if I modify my list and inside 'grades' store another dict, for example: list1=[{'name':"Jon", 'grades':[{'maths': 4, 'biology':5},{'maths': 4, 'biology':5}]}, {'name':"Marry", 'grades':[{'maths': 5, 'biology':4, 'geography': 3}]}] and now I'd like to count the number of dictionaries within 'grades'. So I'd like to get [2,1]

Comment: ok. I got it. this would be [len(list1[i]['grades']) for i in range(0,len(list1))]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way using a list comprehension. Note that in order to take the `len` of the values in `grades` we need to unpack its values. Alternatively you you could simply index on the first position:

```
[len(*i['grades']) for i in list1]
# [2, 3]
```

If there could be dictionaries without the `grades` key in them you could use:

```
[len(*i.get('grades', 0)) for i in list1]
```

Which sets a default value of `0` in the case the key is not contained

Comment: What if I modify my list and inside 'grades' store another dict, for example: list1=[{'name':"Jon", 'grades':[{'maths': 4, 'biology':5},{'maths': 4, 'biology':5}]}, {'name':"Marry", 'grades':[{'maths': 5, 'biology':4, 'geography': 3}]}] and now I'd like to count the number of dictionaries within 'grades'. So I'd like to get [2,1]

Answer (score 0):

I propose the following solution.

```
[len(i['grades'][0]) for i in list1 if 'grades' in i]
```

I check that the key grades be in the dictionary.

[image]